# QUERY Function: How to count with multiple counting criterias

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**[Goal]**
I'm trying to count the number of tickets per employee in one column that has a status with either "Finished," "Finished (Scope)," or "Routed (Sales)" for a specific week. In another column I also want to count the number of tickets for a specific week without criteria. The data that I'm pulling from to count the tickets has the following column names.

Column A: Date,
Column B: Ticket ID,
Column E: Employee,
Column H: Finished Week
Column K: Week

In the formula, you'll notice that it's referring to cell H1, which the cell contains the current week which is this formula: =TODAY()-MOD(TODAY()-2,7)-1

**[Current Formula]**

```html
=QUERY('Data'!$A$3:$J,"Select E,
 COUNT(B) where D matches 'Finished|Finished \(Scope\)|Routed \(Sales\)'
 AND H = "&H1&" GROUP BY E LABEL COUNT(B) 'Total Finished Tickets'",0)
```

**[What it should look like]**
I've created a sample spreadsheet that you can refer to.
Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MQLgt_SSbUIKv1rEwx-Y21hooxNOOgcUm_j1rFehHdg/edit?usp=sharing

**[Issue]**
I was able to create a table that counts the number of tickets per employee with the status as "Finished" OR "Finished (Scope)" OR "Routed (Sales)." Which is the "Current Result" table (Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MQLgt_SSbUIKv1rEwx-Y21hooxNOOgcUm_j1rFehHdg/edit#gid=0).

However, as I tried to add another count criteria, it gave me errors and I don't understand how to properly make this work. I wanted to look like the table of the title "Ideal Result" in the shared link. Can someone please help?

Comment: What about `COUNTISF()` with wild card matching?

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your sheet with a small sample of data in the correct columns, replacing actual names with Name1, Name2, Name3 etc

Comment: Hi everyone, many thanks for responding to my questions. I have created a sample sheet (link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MQLgt_SSbUIKv1rEwx-Y21hooxNOOgcUm_j1rFehHdg/edit#gid=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get two independent counts, you can't use a Where clause because that would exclude cases from both counts, but you could use the fact that Query does not count empty cells something like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({if(regexmatch(D3:D,"Finished$|Finished \(Scope\)$|Routed \(Sales\)$"),true,),E3:E,if(K3:K>=H1,true,)},"select Col2,count(Col3),count(Col1) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 label count(Col1) 'Finished', count(Col3) 'New'",1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Tom Sharpe, I'm really sorry that my question wasn't clear enough. The data that the query is trying to reference has two different types of dates. There is the "Week" column and the "Finished Week" column. Can we use these dates to pull the correct data? I've updated my question and created a sample spreadsheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MQLgt_SSbUIKv1rEwx-Y21hooxNOOgcUm_j1rFehHdg/edit#gid=0).

Comment: Hi - I'm still a bit confused - it looks as if all the sample data are finished but your criteria are "Finished," "Finished (Scope)," or "Routed (Sales)" so that would exclude "Finished (Sales)" ? I still can't quite match your figures but I will post an edited answer later.

Comment: Hi @Tom Sharpe, I sincerely apologize for the delay here. I tried it out and I was able to resolve the issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `pivot` clause to get a breakdown by the Status column like this:

```
=query(
  Data!A3:J, 
  "select E, count(E) 
   where H = " & E4 & " 
   group by E 
   pivot D 
   label E 'Employee' ", 
  0 
)
```

The downside is that the grand total must then be calculated separately, but that can be done with a simple `sum()` formula.

Alternatively, get the totals first, and then do a lookup to get the number of finished tickets, like this:

```
=query(
  Data!A2:J, 
  "select E, count(D) 
   where H = " & E4 & " 
   group by E 
   label E 'Employee', count(D) 'Total new tickets' ", 
  0 
)
```

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      E12:E, 
      query(
        Data!A2:J, 
        "select E, count(D) 
         where H = " & E4 & " 
         and (D = 'Finished' or D = 'Finished (Scope)')
         group by E 
         label count(D) 'Finished tickets' ", 
        1 
      ), 
      2, 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Note that this serves just to illustrate how to aggregate the data into a report. Your question leaves it unclear as to which status values should be counted for each type of aggregation. No rows with status `Routed (Sales)` appear in the data, and I cannot see how the expected results you show could be derived from the data.

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MQLgt_SSbUIKv1rEwx-Y21hooxNOOgcUm_j1rFehHdg/edit#gid=0).

> H1, which the cell contains the current week which is this formula
>
> `=TODAY()-MOD(TODAY()-2,7)-1`

You may want to try the `weeknum()` function.

Comment: Hi @doubleunary, many thanks for responding. I've tried your solution, however it wasn't the result that I was looking for. So I've updated my question and shared a sample spreadsheet (link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MQLgt_SSbUIKv1rEwx-Y21hooxNOOgcUm_j1rFehHdg/edit#gid=0) for better clarity on what I want to do. Hope you can help.

Comment: Edited the answer and inserted formulas in the sample spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi @doubleunary, I appreciate you checking and re-answering. I was able to resolve the issue!!